# Declaring a function which has a function inside using a sort method

Tags: javascript

Lets say I'm trying to make more "programmatically" a function `sort(fn)`
I'm just trying the way of declare a function which summarizes all in one.

I got this:

```
myArrayObjs=[[
  { name: "charles", numb: 28 },
  { name: "Theo ", numb: 22 },
  { name: " Sagna", numb: 27  }
]
```

I want to sort this, getting a order of array having in mind its numb obj,
thus basically could be this:

```
myArrayObjs.sort(function Objs(obj1,obj2){return obj1.numb-obj2.numb})
```

Lets say if I console log this just the way it is:

```
console.log(myArrayObjs.sort(function Objs(obj1,obj2){return obj1.numb-obj2.numb}))
```

the return would be

```
3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: "Theo ", numb: 22}
1: {name: " Sagna", numb: 27}
2: {name: "charles", numb: 28}
length: 3__proto__: Array(0)
```

PERFECT!!!

But the point is: How can I summarize all formerly exposed in a general function?I could invoke at anytime just setting the right parameters?

What I tried was:

```
function myNewArray(myArrayObjs,obj1,obj2)
{
 myArrayObjs.sort(function Objs(obj1,obj2)
  {
    return obj1-obj2
  }
 )
}
```

But when I try to `console.log` it, it hits back saying the parameters `obj1` and `obj2` are "no defined" or some like.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to return it: `return myArrayObjs.sort...`

Comment: @georg in fairness, sorting mutates the array, so you shouldn't necessarily need to return in.

Comment: @VLAZ, sure, but I presume the OP is doing `console.log(thisFunc(...))`

Comment: @georg also in fairness, I am not sure *what* is happening. OP mentions that `obj1` and `obj2` are not defined, so perhaps the `console.log` is inside `myNewArray` function Is not exactly clear what is wrong and why, without knowing *what* OP wants to do with this and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj1` and `obj2` in sort callback are two objects in `myArrayObjs` array, `sort` function will pass these to your callback, so your `myNewArray` function should receive field name that will be use for sort instead `obj1` and `obj2`, example:

```
function myNewArray(myArrayObjs, field)
{
    return myArrayObjs.sort(function Objs(obj1, obj2)
        {
            return obj1[field] - obj2[field]
        }
    )
}

let result = myNewArray(myArrayObjs, 'numb')
```